# Android - Any way to style a button background but leave the rest as it was?

Tags: android

Is there any way in Android to style the background gradient of a button without altering the rest of it?

I wanted to make a button that was just like a regular button but with a different gradient.   I made a 3x3 grid of buttons in a table layout.   The first button was like the XML here, the others had no background attribute.

```
   <Button android:id="@+id/DemoButton"
    android:layout_width="105sp"
    android:layout_height="105sp"
    android:background="@drawable/button1"
    android:onClick="theButtonHandler"
    android:text="Fee">
  </Button>
```

My style was like this . . .

```
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_pressed="true" >
   <shape>
      <gradient
         android:startColor="#5555AA"
         android:endColor="#000033"
         android:angle="270" />
   </shape>
 </item>
 <item>
   <shape>
      <gradient
         android:startColor="#BBBBDD"
         android:endColor="#BB9988"
         android:angle="270"/>
      <corners android:bottomRightRadius="3dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="3dp"
          android:topLeftRadius="3dp" android:topRightRadius="3dp"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

I had to put the corner radii in because the new button had sharp 90 degree corners.     The result looked like this:
[image]

. . . It's bigger than the other buttons and I had to code-in rounded corners,even though the only attribute I was changing was the "android:background". How can I just change the background?     Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look on the drawables the Android uses for Buttons, you'll see that there always is an amount of pixels left transparent near the borders of the image. I assume that the image you're using does not have any transparent borders. To make it look equal to Android drawables you should add those borders. You can browse your `android-sdk/platforms/<some-platform>/data/res/<some-drawable-folder>` folders to see how the images are designed. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change it to

```
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_pressed="true" >
   <shape>
      <gradient
         android:startColor="#5555AA"
         android:endColor="#000033"
         android:angle="270" />
       <corners
   android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
   android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
   android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
   android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
   </shape>
 </item>
 <item>
   <shape>
      <gradient
         android:startColor="#BBBBDD"
         android:endColor="#BB9988"
         android:angle="270"/>
       <corners
   android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
   android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
   android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
   android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```